# Reasons for a declined flag

Tags: discussion, flagging

I raised an off topic flag with the specialisation of "Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with electronics design)" for the question [IT TTT block in assembly language](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/367427/it-ttt-block-in-assembly-language) which was declined. I would like to know why I was wrong to flag it so I don't make the same mistake again.

Would the decliner please enlighten me how I was wrong?

Comment: I agree with Olin. Assembly is quite literally a hardware-based programming language as you're dealing with register manipulation with processing units. Programming a chip utilizing Assembly is, in fact, considered on-topic with electronic design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a mod, so had nothing to do with declining the flag.

However, that question is about computer architecture, which is on topic here.  The question itself isn't great because it gives very little context, and doesn't even speak to anyone not having detailed knowledge of its tiny corner of the world.  But that doesn't make it off topic.

Your flag was correctly declined.